# How to attach concrete to wood?

Tags: concrete, mounting

I'm planning a wooden table with concrete legs. I will use a U-shape or O-Shape for the legs.
Should i use screws to attach the legs to the slab or is there a better way?
I thought of placing a metal angle in the concrete but i dont know if its the perfect plan to prevent the table from wobbling (if thats the right word)

EDIT:
i didn't use the concrete legs idea and made a table with steel legs.
[image: raw plank - oak middle piece]

[image: finished table]

Comment: I found this site useful for the types of fasteners available.  http://www.familyhandyman.com/DIY-Projects/Concrete---Brick/Concrete/how-to-choose-and-use-concrete-fasteners/Step-By-Step

Comment: Howdy. Did you ever finish this project? I wonder how it came out :)

Comment: sadly i had no time to make concrete Legs for that table.

Comment: it turns out that there are other difficulties when you attach something to a 5cm tree. For example you have to oil all sides so prevent the tree from twisting. the other thing is: i have not planed the board. i attached it to 5mm steel legs which started to bend to the wood. so the wooden board has more power than the steel. i will make some pictures. but one day i want to try that concrete legs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With out any design sketch, a good way to bond wood to concrete is using `threaded anchors`  or `threaded inserts`

The difficult part is placing these inside the concrete column, to be level and not get dirty from concrete.

[image]

So using a fairly large size, so its easier to clean later, and easier to screw into.

Basically you would then insert a metal shaft in the wooden part and use a long screw that goes throught the wooden shaft freely but its head will clam the shaft.. and when you screw it into the concrete threaded anchor you essentially pull the wood tightly to the concrete pillar..

I could not find a diagram that illustrates this but this picture depicts the concept

[image]

So imagine the top of the screw, the part of your wooden table.. and the bottom part the concrete pillar, but using the threaded insert, instead of that bolt in the picture.

I have seen this used in building public park benches, with wooden planks fastened to concrete pillars... it is highly durable and very vandal proof.

But you might consider putting in three studs per column.. Three, in a triangle shape.. as this helps stabilize heavy objects. Or four in a SQUARE shape.. Using 1 you will need some sort of cross member or brace.. 2 is almost useless as you still need cross members or braces.

Comment: Very nice. I will try a solution where no screw is seen from the top.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid splitting the concrete, the best mechanism seems to be to use metal brackets bolted to the wood that go round the horizontal part of the concrete legs.

Having screws into the concrete could lead to the concrete splitting, although a metal bracket embedded in the concrete could be strong enough for most purposes.